# tool for finding out which Custom master page being used

Tags: 2007, master-page, custom-masterpage, tools

I am trying to find a tool, that tells me which Custom master page is being used by a web/site, I tried google it but couldn't find anything relative.

Cheers

Comment: `SPWeb.MasterUrl`....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple PowerShell script would do it. There's a `MasterUrl` and `CustomMasterUrl` property on the SPWeb object, so you could just do something simple like `Get-SPSite | Get-SPWeb | % {"Site: " + $_.Url + " Master: "+ $_.MasterUrl}` to list out the master for every web.

Comment: Question is tagged '2007', no powershell

Comment: PowerShell is available in both 2007 and 2010...

Comment: Thanks Webdes03, I knew this script already but I am looking for a tool as i have to go through 100's of pages. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: I can't think of a tool that will give you just the master page information. Perhaps one of the big name site administration tools can help with it, but then you're talking about a pretty significant investment to stand up a major tool just for this. You can build/output your report however you need it formatted with PowerShell, regardless of if it's 2, 20, 200, 2,000, or 20,000 sites. We'll need to see some actual requirements in your question in order to guide you.

Comment: because I already had addresses of all the websites, I find it easier to use SharePoint Designer :), thanks for your help guys

Comment: PowerShell itself exists but not the SharePoint cmdlets you suggest. You would need to use New-Object [...], which would still work I guess.

Comment: @Louis, correct. Not a straight port to 2007, I wouldn't mislead that there's no PowerShell capability at all though.

Answer (score 2):

Open Site in SharePoint Designer 2007, In "_catalogs" folder, you will find a sub-folder named as "masterpage", extending this folder will display you masterpage being used for that specific site/web.

You can follow this link if you dont know how to open a site in sharepoint designer 2007

[Opening a Site in Sharepoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/open-a-sharepoint-site-HA010131345.aspx)

and you will "_catalogs" folder in "Folder List" on top left hand side.

Cheers